# Using getline in an overloaded input operator

Tags: c++, input, operator-keyword, getline

`Book.h`:

```
#ifndef BOOKDATE
#define BOOKDATE

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Book{
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Book&);
private:
    std::string title, author;
    int number;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Book&);

#endif // BOOKDATE
```

`Book.cpp`:

```
#include "BookDate.h"    
using namespace std;

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Book& rhs){
    getline(is, rhs.title); 
    getline(is, rhs.author);
    is >> rhs.number;
    if(!is)
        rhs = Book();
    return is;
}
```

I was wondering how exactly I should approach creating the input operator for the `Book` class. The `title` and `author` will be more than one word, so it fits that I need to use `getline` to receive that data. The issue then with `getline` is that it may pick up any `'\n'` left in the stream since `cin` was last used. For instance;

```
int x;
cin >> x; //newline is not extracted and left behind
Book a;
cin >> a; //"title" is automatically made empty!
```

I could instead use `cin.ignore(256, '\n')` but whose responsibility, the user's or class `author`'s, is it to use this? Does the user use `.ignore` before he inputs a `Book` object or does the class author put `.ignore` at the beginning of the input operation?

It seems that in the former case the user would have to understand an `.ignore` method is needed but in doing so has to understand the implementation of the `Book`'s input operator, which is not desirable. In the latter case, putting `.ignore` in the operator means my operator may not adapt to certain circumstances, since it always expects to encounter a newline before processing. For instance reading from an input file with data such as:

```
book1
author1
1

book2
author2
2
```

Means `book1` gets ignored by `cin.ignore(256,'\n')`.

Comment: i would say that `operator>>()` should assume the file is in the correct position to begin reading.

Comment: Also that it is not unreasonable for `operator>>()` to skip whitespace before reading.

Comment: normal convention would be to assume a stream in correctly positioned at the start of the object to be read.  You define whether your object can or cannot begin with a newline.  Your caller is responsible to position the stream

Answer (score 0):

To make your `operator>>` behave more like the operators for the built in types, you can use the `ws` manipulator to skip whitespace before you read your input.

Just use

```
is >> ws;
```

at the beginning of your input operator, and the stream will be positioned at the first non-whitespace character after the current position.

Answer (score 0):

To overload the extraction operator properly you can change your input format to be a sequence of three variables that you want to populate, namely:

```
(title, author, number)
```

and modify your `operator>>` to:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Book& rhs){
    // just a suggestion: it is better if there is no input to do nothing
    if(!is) return is;
    string title, author;
    int number;
    char par1, comma, par2;
    cin >> skipws >> par1 >> title >> comma >> author>> comma >> number >> par2;
    if (par1 != '(' || comma != ',' || par1 != ')'){
        // set failbit to indicate invalid input format
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
    }
    rhs(title, author, number); 
    return is;
}
```

Comment: You say it is illegal because it is private, but operator>> is declared as a friend function? Actually I cut out of lot from my example to keep it short just to focus on the operator>>. As per your second suggestion, it doesn't account for a title or author that could be multiple words, which was why I said I needed getline, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score -1):

put `is.ignore();` before `getline(is, rhs.title);`

Comment: What does this do? Please add an explanation for this to your answer.

Comment: i dont really know :D. seen that this question hasnt been answered for 4 years i decided to ask it again but i also checked ~7 questions stackoverflow suggested as "similar" (the first one was this) and on the 5th or 6th i found this command, i tried it and it worked